# Could not verify St device error occurs in STM32CubeIDE

Tags: stm32, iot, openocd, bluepill

I am trying to run Blinky on stm32 bluepill but I am getting error message....."Could not verify ST device! Please verify that the latest version of GDB-server is used for the connection"
I have also edited the stm32f1x.cfg file but the issue is same.
Debug Probe is ST-LINK(OpenOCD).

Comment: Blue pill might have a clone of stm32 with a different ChipID. Show all the messages from OpenOCD, there might be something like "Unexpected Idcode"

Comment: Did you replace the ChipID in the cfg file?
Dump the full OpenOCD log here as suggested.

Comment: bluepills nowadays very rarely use original STM chips